# Converting raw SQL to Django ORM QuerySet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

This is my SQL:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT generate_series(start_date::date, end_date::date, '1 day'::interval) AS dates, * FROM api_event ORDER BY dates")
```

How can i do this using Django ORM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I find decision. Maybe someone need this to:

On Django ORM this will be like that:

```
Event.objects.annotate(dates=Func(F('start_date'), F('end_date'), Value('1 day'), function='generate_series')).all()
```

Comment: Any idea how to output timestamps from the function? I want to respect daylight savings time.